# Sublime text 3 перенос по регулярному выражению

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sublime-text-3, replace

Как в Sublime text 3 по регулярному выражению перенести коды стран (те что в скобках) в начало строки? Со всеми странами.
Например было **Afghanistan (AF)** и после replace-а стало **(AF) Afghanistan**.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текстовые данные необходимо размещать в вопросе в виде текста.

Comment: найти `(.+)(\s+)(\(.+\))\n` заменить на `$3$2$1\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярное выражение для ваших данных:

```
(.+)\s(\([A-Z]{2}\))
```

Заменить на:

```
$2 $1
```